# An alternative proof for Riesz Representation Theorem for $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

During my class in real analysis, my teacher mentioned an alternative method to prove Riesz's theorem for $C([0,1])$. He just mentioned the method, but did not prove it. (A usual way of doing this is provided here: [Riesz representation theorem for $C([0,1])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3032271/792125))

> **Step 1:** Let $\Lambda$ be a nonnegative linear functional on $C[0,1]$, and define
> $$F(t)=\inf\left\{\Lambda(f):f\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t]}\right\}$$ $F(t)$
> is nondecreasing function of $t$,  and $F(t)$ is right continuous.
>
> **Step 2:** Let $\mu$ be the measure on $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mu([0,t])=F(t)$. Show that $$\Lambda(f)=\int fd\mu$$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$.

I am trying to prove this using his method, but I get stuck for a while and do not have much progress. Here are my progress so far:

*First, I try to show $F(t)$ is a nondecreasing function. Let $0<t_1<t_2\leq 1$, since $\Lambda(f_i)\leq F(t_i)+\varepsilon$ for $i=1,2$, then $f=f_1+f_2\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t_1]\cup[0,t_2]}$ and $\Lambda(f)\leq F(t_1)+F(t_2)+2\varepsilon$.
My aim is to show that $F(t_1)\leq F(t_2)$, but I cannot get a lower bound for $\Lambda(f)$. If I should use Urysohn lemma, how should I find the two disjoint sets to make separations?*

**Added:** For any $0<t_1<t_2\leq 1$, observe that
$$\{\Lambda(f):f\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t_2]}\}\subset\{\Lambda(f):f\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t_1]}\}$$

Take infimum on both sides, $F(t_1)\leq F(t_2)$.

*Second, I try to show $F(t)$ is right continuous, i.e. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)=F(t)$$
I proceed this way:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf\left\{\Lambda(f):f\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t+\frac{1}{n}]}\right\}$$
From here, I'd like to take intersection over $n\ge 1$, but I'm not sure whether I can do this to get $F(t)$.*

**Added:** For fixed $t\in(0,1]$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, choose $f_1(x)\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t]}$ s.t. $\Lambda(f_1)\leq F(t)+\varepsilon$. Then define $f_2(x)=f_1(x)+\varepsilon$, then $f_2(t)\ge 1+\varepsilon$. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large s.t. for all $n>N$, $f_2(t+\frac{1}{n})>1$ by continuity of $f_2(x)$. Hence $f_2(x)\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t+\frac{1}{n}]}$. Plug this result into $\Lambda(\cdot)$ and take infimum on both sides, we get the estimate:
$$F\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\Lambda(f_2)=\Lambda(f_2-f_1+f_1)=\varepsilon+\Lambda(f_1)\leq F(t)+2\varepsilon$$
Let $n\to\infty$ and $\varepsilon\to 0$, we prove right continuity:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)=F(t)$$

*For Step 2, though I do not know how to write this in detail currently, I think the process should be similar to the method provided in the post I mentioned. The key in this step is to partition $[0,1]$ into closed sets $[a_i,b_i]$ of size less than $\delta$, and to define $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ (like in the post I mentioned) to approximate $f(x)$, and then finish the argument by reaching a bound for $\left|\Lambda(f)-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)d\mu\right|$, where the bound should consist of $\|\Lambda(f)\|$ and the measure $\mu$. But I really do not know how to reach this step.*

**Added:** By definition of measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$, $\mu([0,1])=F(1)=\inf\{\Lambda(f):f\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,1]}\}=\Lambda(\textbf{1}_{[0,1]})$. WLOG, we can assume that $\Lambda(\textbf{1})=1$. Hence, $\mu([0,1])=1$. Since $f\in C([0,1])$, it is bounded. WLOG, we can assume $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$.
To show $\ge$, if we change $f$ to $1-f$ in the inequality, and since $\Lambda(\textbf{1})=\mu([0,1])$ as we have just assumed, we achieve equality. So this side is trivial.
To show $\leq$, let $\{[a_j,b_j]\}_{j=1}^{n}\subset [0,1]$ be a finite disjoint collection with $b_j-a_j\leq\varepsilon$, and $\mu\{x: f(x)\notin\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}[a_j,b_j]\}\leq\varepsilon$. Define $E_j=\{x:f(x)\in[a_j,b_j]\}$. Note that $\{E_j\}$'s are disjoint. Hence by Urysohn's lemma, $\exists\{g_j(x)\}\in[0,1]$ continuous s.t. for every $j=1,\ldots,n$,
$$g_j(x)=\begin{cases}1, &x\in E_j\\0, &x\notin E_j\end{cases}$$
Then by partition of unity, define $h_1=g_1$, $h_j=(1-g_1)\ldots(1-g_{j-1})g_j$ for $2\leq j\leq n-1$, and $h_n=(1-g_1)\ldots(1-g_{n-1})$. Then $\sum_{j=1}^{n}h_j(x)=1$ and $h_j(x)=1$ on $E_j$. Then $f=\sum_{j=1}^{n}f\cdot h_j$, where $f\cdot h_j\ge a_j\textbf{1}_{E_j}$. Using this estimate, we can show $\leq$:
$$\int_{0}^{1}fd\mu\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_j\mu(E_j)+\varepsilon\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_j+\varepsilon)\mu(E_j)+\varepsilon\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}\Lambda(f\cdot h_j)+2\varepsilon=\Lambda(f)+2\varepsilon$$
Let $\varepsilon\to 0$, done.

Can anyone help me to complete the proof based on this method? I'll update accordingly if I have more progress. Thank you!

Comment: You're making this too complicated, I'm afraid. Monotony of $F$ is almost trivial, since for $t_1<t_2$, $\textbf{1}_{[0,t_1]}\le \textbf{1}_{[0,t_2]}$, thus $\{f:f\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t_2]}\}\subset\{f:f\ge\textbf{1}_{[0,t_1]}\}$. Much in the same spirit, $\textbf{1}_{[0,t]}=\inf_{n\ge1}\textbf{1}_{[0,t+1/n]}$, and since $\inf$ is pretty much associative and commutative, this gives right continuity of $F$ at once.

Comment: @ProfessorVector True, I've figured this out on my own, and I'll update accordingly. Do you have some ideas on step 2? I think using partition of unity is necessary, but I'm still struggling with how to use it.

Comment: As long as you don't really update  according to your progress, *as promised*, you're wasting time of those who want to help you, not knowing what you found out, already. I'm out of this.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I've updated the first two steps. For step 3, as I've said, I'm still struggling with using partition of unity. Can you possibly give me some hints, or write an asnwer to describe your method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a feasible way to complete part 3. The idea is to write the integral representation as a Riemann integral (functions of BV), and use sums to approximate.

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{0=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=1\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$. By definition of measure $\mu$ s.t. $F(t)=\mu([0,t])$, we can express$$\int_{0}^{1}fd\mu=\int_{0}^{1}fdF(x)$$
We can approximate the integral on the right by sums, $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_{k+1})\left(F(x_{k+1})-F(x_k)\right)$$, as $|\mathcal{P}|\to 0$. Since $F(t)$ is right continuous, we need to split into two cases: $f(0)=0$ and $f(0)=a\neq 0$ for $a$ any constant. For the first case, define the step function s.t. for $|x_{k+1}-x_k|<\delta$,
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k)(\textbf{1}_{(x_k,x_{k+1}]})$$
Since we have assumed $f(0)=0$, we can exclude the first term and hence $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_{k+1})(\textbf{1}_{[0,x_{k+1}]}-\textbf{1}_{[0,x_k]})$$
By definition of $F(t)$, for any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$\left|\Lambda(f_n)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_{k+1})\left(F(x_{k+1})-F(x_k)\right)\right|<\varepsilon$$
Since $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_{k+1})\left(F(x_{k+1})-F(x_k)\right)\to\int_{0}^{1}fdF(x)$ as $|\mathcal{P}|\to 0$,
$$\left|\Lambda(f_n)-\int_{0}^{1}fdF(x)\right|<\varepsilon$$
Note that for every $x\in[0,1]$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. Take supremum on both sides, $\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Thus,
$$|\Lambda(f_n)-\Lambda(f)|\leq\|\Lambda\|\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}<\|\Lambda\|\varepsilon$$
, where $\|\Lambda\|$ is the operator norm. Note that $\|\Lambda\|<\infty$, since nonnegative linear functionals on $C[0,1]$ are continuous. By the above two inequalities,
$$\left|\Lambda(f)-\int_{0}^{1}fd\mu\right|=\left|\Lambda(f)-\int_{0}^{1}fdF(x)\right|<(\|\Lambda\|+1)\varepsilon$$
Let $\varepsilon\to 0$, done with first case.
For the second case, consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-a$ and plug in the result we yield in the first case:
$$\Lambda(f)=\Lambda(g)+a\Lambda(\textbf{1}_{[0,1]})=\int_{0}^{1}gd\mu+aF(1)=\int_{0}^{1}f d\mu$$
Done with second case.